# Removing white space in Photoshop

Tags: photoshop, action

I have 500 icon images in Photoshop that have varying white space around each of the objects.  I was wondering if there's any way to run an action through photoshop that'll crop each image so that it removes the white space around each of the icon (if not, oh well, I was just curious).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There's a trim item in the menus that will look at the top left pixel and remove the contiguous pixels of the same colour from around the image, this has the effect of cropping out the background.  It should be available for batch operations and macros, is that what you need?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know how to automate this in Photoshop, but [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org) can do it. The Windows binaries are easy to install. There don't seem to be Mac binaries though.

[Trim or the 'Auto-Crop' Operator](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/crop/#trim)

> The "-trim" operator is a very close relation to the highly versatile "-crop" operator discussed above. However instead of supplying an argument, this operator attempts to remove any borders or edges of an image which did does not change in color or transparency. In other words it removes the 'boring' bits surrounding an image.